# can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple - sum up 2 variables after an if statement in django/python

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am looking to sum 2 variables together and getting error: 'can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple' (error edited since original post)

In summary, I have a sort of todo list. Every time an `action` is validated by creating an `Validation` object model, the `action` is given 1 point.

If all `actions` within the `task` have received 1 point, then the `task` is considered completed.

I am stuck at the sum of points.

I feel I need to write a sort of for loop after my if statement to add up each point in each action together. I tried different combos, but none seem to work.

Am I getting this wrong? (I am sure my code is also far from being optimal, so I wont be offended if you offer an alternative)

**models**

```
class Action(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name",max_length=100, blank=True)

class ValidationModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Action, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)

class Task(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="title",max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
    venue = models.ManyToManyField(Action, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
    
class TaskAccepted(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Task,null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='task_accepted')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    accepted_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

**views**

```
def function(request, taskaccepted_id):
    instance_1 = Action.objects.filter(task__id=taskaccepted_id)
    action_count = instance_1.count()
    instance_2 = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=taskaccepted_id)
sum_completed =()

    for action in instance1:
        
        for in_action in action.validationmodel_set.all()[:1]:
            latest_point = in_action.created_at
            action_completed = in_action
            if latest_point > instance_2.accepted_on:
                action_completed = 1   
            else:
                action_completed = 0
            sum_completed += venue_completed #<-- can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple
```

Comment: If you want to add to `sum_completed` you can use `sum_completed += ...`. `sum` is used for adding all values in a list.

Comment: Looks like i wasnt looking at the right thing then! I did 'sum_completed += venue_completed', which returns: 'local variable 'sum_completed' referenced before assignment'. I normally add something like `sum_completed +=()` at the top of the function to get rid of this, but this time this is not working. Any idea?

Comment: can you edit ? as you tried another approach as per comment?

Comment: All done. (formatting has gone a bit wrong) the new error message I get is: `can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was here:

```
sum_completed =()
```

It should have been

```
sum_completed =0
```

and @ivvija works.

To conclude, if someone end up in the same scenario as me:

```
def function(request, taskaccepted_id):
    instance_1 = Action.objects.filter(task__id=taskaccepted_id)
    action_count = instance_1.count()
    instance_2 = get_object_or_404(Task, pk=taskaccepted_id)
sum_completed =0

    for action in instance1:
        
        for in_action in action.validationmodel_set.all()[:1]:
            latest_point = in_action.created_at
            action_completed = in_action
            if latest_point > instance_2.accepted_on:
                action_completed = 1   
            else:
                action_completed = 0
            sum_completed += action_completed
```